# Set negative value to zero in equation in Gekko?

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

How do I set all the negative value of a variable to zero in an equation. I've tried using `m.max2(0,W)` so when W is negative I get zero but when it's positive I get the value but since W is defined as `W.dt()==s*p` the value seems to be trailing I cant' set the lower bound to zero because I need the negative value elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `max2` function is a Mathematical Program with Complementarity Constraints (MPCC) and sometimes has a hard time converging when at `W=0` because it is a saddle point for optimization. Another option is the `max3` function but this requires a mixed integer solver that can require more time to compute a solution. A third option is to use a function such as `w * (0.5*tanh(b*w)+0.5)` to get a continuously differentiable approximation to the max function. You can set the `b` to be a higher value but then it makes the problem harder to solve.

[image: tanh function]

Another option is to successively solve the problem with higher values of `b`, like a barrier function in the interior point method.

Here is an example script that has all three functions:

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
w = m.Param(np.linspace(-10,10,101))
x = m.Intermediate(w * 0.5*(m.tanh(10*w)+1))
y = m.max2(w,0)
z = m.max3(w,0)

m.options.IMODE=2
m.solve()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(w,x,'ko',label='x=0.5 w (tanh(10w)+1)')
plt.plot(w,y,'b-',label='y=min2(w,0)')
plt.plot(w,z,'r--',label='z=min3(w,0)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: max functions]